# Tom-select with bootstrap 5 theme differs visually from bootstrap 5.1.3 styled select

Tags: javascript, symfony, sass, bootstrap-5, tom-select

### Premise

In order to display selects the same on Windows, Linux and Mac, in my project, i am using combination of:

- `tom-select v2.0.1` [JavaScript library](https://github.com/orchidjs/tom-select);
- `Bootstrap v5.1.3` [frontend framework](https://getbootstrap.com);
- `Symfony v5.4.5` [backend framework](https://symfony.com).

I have set up SCSS files of `bootstrap` and `tom-select`.

Frontend packages are managed by `Yarn` package manager.

I work with SCSS because i am overriding *Bootstrap* variables with custom sets for different themes inside the site.

My working configuration with *Symfony* and `Webpack Encore` has SCSS and JS separated (CSS is not included in JavaScript). CSS is compiled from SCSS that includes tom-select SCSS.

Webpage includes CSS (Bootstrap + theme customizations + tom-select) and JS (bootstrap and tom-select separately).

### Problem

1. Select shows with smaller than default in *bootstrap 5* `box-shadow` around its field.
2. Select element has +2px height when compared with default in *bootstrap 5*
3. Select element dropdown starts farther away from its field when compared with default in *bootstrap 5*

Number 2 and 3 are mild inconveniences, but 1-st one i consider a problem.

### Illustration

[image: screenshot of input and tom-select fields in Firefox]

### Things i tried

1. Redefine *tom-select* variable `$input-focus-width`, but it did not succeed;
2. Tried different arrangement of includes in SCSS main override (those configurations that worked still exposed the problem at hand);
3. Introduced additional CSS rules (see Update 1)

### Code

> main override SCSS

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

$input-border-color: $gray-500;
$form-select-border-color: $gray-500;
$input-group-addon-border-color: $gray-500;
$input-focus-width: 0.25rem; /* no effect on tom-select */

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~tom-select/src/scss/tom-select.bootstrap5";
```

> main SCSS imports override

```
@import "./main_override";

body
{
    background: #f0ede8 !important;
}

/* other styles follow */
```

> TWIG template (page that includes compiled CSS)

```
{% extends 'base_admin.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}New firm{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('tom_select') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3 class="fix text-center">{% trans from 'menu' %}menu.firm.new{% endtrans %}</h3>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="box-list clearfix">
                    {% if form is defined %}
                        {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'form-firm-create', 'novalidate': 'novalidate', 'autocomplete': 'off'}, 'method': 'POST'}) }}
                            <div class="field-group">
                                {{ form_row(form.isSpecial, {'label_attr': {'class': 'form-group-label'}, 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-btn form-group text-center box-submit">
                                <a class="btn btn-secondary me-1" href="{{ path('firm_list') }}">
                                    <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-left"></i>
                                    <span>{%- trans from 'firms' %}firms.goToList{% endtrans -%}</span>
                                </a>
                                {{ form_widget(form.firmCreate) }}
                            </div>
                        {{ form_end(form) }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

> JavaScript that is executed on page

```
"use strict";

import TomSelect from "tom-select/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js";

$(function()
{
    new TomSelect("#firm_create_isSpecial", {
        allowEmpty: false,
        create: false,
        sortField: {
            direction: "asc",
            field: "text"
        }
    });
});
```

### Conclusion

What i am doing wrong?

Is there an error in my config?

Thank you for ideas and suggestions.

### Update 1

With the following rules added i got same width box-shadow and correct inner border color, yet there is a flash when clicking on select because of field's width increase by 2px in order to get right width of control.

> Added CSS rules

```
.ts-wrapper.form-select .ts-control,
.ts-wrapper.form-select.focus .ts-control
{
    border: 1px solid #fff !important;
}

.ts-wrapper.form-select.single.input-active .ts-control
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
}
.ts-wrapper.form-select.single.input-active.focus .ts-control
{
    border: 1px solid #86b7fe !important;
}

.my-ts-select.focus .ts-control,
.my-ts-select:focus .ts-control
{
    border: 1px solid #86b7fe !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem #b7d5ff !important;
    outline: 0;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.ts-control
{
    border: none !important;
}
```

> I imagine that provided CSS rules can be optimized. Do not hesitate to provide your suggestions.

### Update 2

> Tried some more modifications to CSS and discovered that removing class: `form-select` from rendered field makes `tom-select` control to conform to `bootstrap` styling (without additional styling)!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get *tom-select* to display itself in *Bootstrap styling* Use JavaScript to remove class 'form-select' before setting up the field.

```
"use strict";

import TomSelect from "tom-select/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js";

window.addEventListener('load', (event) =>
{
    // remove form-select class from tom-select element
    document.getElementById("test_is_special").classList.remove('form-select');

    // initialize tom-select
    new TomSelect("#test_is_special", {
        allowEmpty: false,
        create: false,
        sortField: {
            direction: "asc",
            field: "text"
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem using `tom-select` version `2.0.1`.

After upgrading the JS and CSS to version [2.0.3](https://github.com/orchidjs/tom-select/releases/tag/v2.0.3) this problem is now fixed.

I can use `form-control` and even `form-control-sm` and it matches other inputs and selects in BS5.